# Is my company monitoring traffic in my personal profile through mdm policies/VPN on my work profile?

Tags: vpn, work-profiles

My company is very high on security.

It's difficult to work with the company laptop remotely because once it goes to sleep(after about 2 mins of being idle) it disconnects from the internet and you need to log back in, connect to the wifi, connect to a VPN with your credentials, authorize the VPN via your phone and then click accept before you get internet access on the computer again.

In other to reply emails and slack messages faster, I had to add a work profile, I installed the required apps, accepted polices etc.

communications apps that connect to the company domains or work apps have to be funneled via a VPN (required installation by the company).

So basically these apps don't work without the vpn.

My main concern is that this VPN might be monitoring traffic in my personal profile although I have premium proton VPN installed, I don't feel entirely safe about it.

I've checked online and the answers I've seen are generic.

Any help here?

Comment: Sorry but your question is too confusing to being answered. 1. why do you talk about "company laptop" - this site is about Android only. 2. you forgot to tell us details about your Android device: what MDM is installed? 3. you can check yon your own if traffic interception is done, simply look at the certificate list of a site like stackoverflow.com and compare it to a device that is not from your company.